# Merge pandas dataframe with unequal length

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have two Pandas dataframes that I would like to merge into one. They have unequal length, but contain some of the same information.

Here is the first dataframe:

```
BOROUGH  TYPE  TCOUNT
  MAN    SPORT   5
  MAN    CONV    3
  MAN    WAGON   2
  BRO    SPORT   2
  BRO    CONV    3
```

Where column `A` specifies a location, `B` a category and `C` a count.

And the second:

```
BOROUGH  CAUSE  CCOUNT
  MAN   ALCOHOL   5
  MAN     SIZE    3
  BRO   ALCOHOL   2
```

Here `A` is again the same Location as in the other dataframe. But `D` is another category, and `E` is the count for `D` in that location.

What I want (and haven't been able to do) is to get the following:

```
BOROUGH   TYPE   TCOUNT  CAUSE  CCOUNT
  MAN    SPORT     5    ALCOHOL    5
  MAN    CONV      3      SIZE     3
  MAN    WAGON     2      NaN     NaN
  BRO    SPORT     2    ALCOHOL    2
  BRO    CONV      3      NaN     NaN
```

"-" can be anything. Preferably a string saying "Nothing". If they default to NaN values, I guess it's just a matter of replacing those with a string.

**EDIT**:
Output:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 233 entries, 0 to 232
Data columns (total 3 columns):
BOROUGH                          233 non-null object
CONTRIBUTING FACTOR VEHICLE 1    233 non-null object
RCOUNT                           233 non-null int64
dtypes: int64(1), object(2)
memory usage: 7.3+ KB
None

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 83 entries, 0 to 82
Data columns (total 3 columns):
BOROUGH                83 non-null object
VEHICLE TYPE CODE 1    83 non-null object
VCOUNT                 83 non-null int64
dtypes: int64(1), object(2)
memory usage: 2.6+ KB
None
```

Comment: pd.merge(df_One, df_Two, left_on=['A', 'B'], right_on=['A', 'D'])   Can you try this ?

Comment: OK I see your issue, df1 has 233 rows but df2 has only 83 rows so you get nulls due to uneqal lengths, what are you expecting as I expect this to be expected operation

Comment: I was hoping I would be able to merge the two dataframes. Basically fill all the missing values in df2. So if df1 has 47 values for BRONX but df2 only has 17, I would fill the remaining 30 values in df2 with [BRONX, NOTHING,0]. And then I would be able to merge the two dataframes. The same would apply to the other boroughs, QUEENS, MANHATTAN, BROOKLYN and STATEN ISLAND

Comment: As it stands this won't work because in df2 you have multiple entries for borough so it's ambiguous which one should be matched up so if you did `df1.merge(df2, how='left)` this will generate a df with 3869 rows so you're going have to clean up the data or decide on some other criteria for the join/merge this has nothing to do with pandas this is a data issue

Comment: Yeah okay. Then it might be easier for me to go with two separate dataframes. Thank you for your time though

Answer (score 6):

Perform a `left` type [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.0/merging.html#database-style-dataframe-joining-merging) on columns 'A','B' for the lhs and 'A','D' for the rhs as these are your key columns

```
In [16]:
df.merge(df1, left_on=['A','B'], right_on=['A','D'], how='left')
​
Out[16]:
   A  B  C   D   E
0  1  1  3   1   5
1  1  2  2   2   3
2  1  3  1 NaN NaN
3  2  1  1   1   2
4  2  2  4 NaN NaN
```

**EDIT**

Your question has changed but essentially here you can use `combine_first`:

```
In [26]:
merged = df.combine_first(df1)
merged

Out[26]:
  BOROUGH    CAUSE  CCOUNT  TCOUNT   TYPE
0     MAN  ALCOHOL       5       5  SPORT
1     MAN     SIZE       3       3   CONV
2     MAN  ALCOHOL       2       2  WAGON
3     BRO      NaN     NaN       2  SPORT
4     BRO      NaN     NaN       3   CONV
```

The `NaN` you see for 'CAUSE' is the string 'NaN', we can use `fillna` to replace these values:

```
In [27]:
merged['CAUSE'] = merged['CAUSE'].fillna('Nothing')
merged['CCOUNT'] = merged['CCOUNT'].fillna(0)
merged

Out[27]:
  BOROUGH    CAUSE  CCOUNT  TCOUNT   TYPE
0     MAN  ALCOHOL       5       5  SPORT
1     MAN     SIZE       3       3   CONV
2     MAN  ALCOHOL       2       2  WAGON
3     BRO  Nothing       0       2  SPORT
4     BRO  Nothing       0       3   CONV
```

Comment: Does it matter if A is actually containing strings? Because my D and E are all being set to NaN. B and D are also strings if that matters

Comment: if the dtypes are not the same then the column dtype becomes mixed and will show as `object`, although this is expected it may give problems when you're comparing against numeric and string values and your output shows you something that looks like numeric/string but in fact is something else, it's better to have homogenous dtypes to avoid this confusion

Comment: Saying that I think in this case it should not matter as you're not merging values as such, so long as the key column dtypes agree then the above shouldn't apply

Comment: Both A, B, D are strings. C and E are ints. I guess that is what's causing problems then? Don't know why it's not working then

Comment: When you have missing values it will convert the dtype to float to represent `NaN` this is expected behaviour as `NaN` cannot be represented in `int`, you can fill the missing values calling `fillna` and then cast the dtype using `astype(int)` on those columns

Comment: The issue is that the entire column D and E are being set to NaN when doing the merge. There are no missing values in either of the two dataframes prior to the merge.

Comment: That shouldn't happen, can you post the output from `df.info()` and `df1.info()` also can you post raw data and code to reproduce your dfs exactly. You can also do another thing to check if the values are matching such as `df['A'].isin(df1['A'])` and likewise `df['B'].isin(df1['D'])` to see if the values are matching

Comment: Hmm. The essence of the question should be the same though. It still doesn't work the way I want it to.

Comment: Can you post links to your raw data, presumably if you ran my code it works?

Comment: The CSV file i'm using: https://www.dropbox.com/s/y6w41bgdu9bqnfm/MotorIncidents_2012_2016.csv?dl=0

Here is my code:
http://pastebin.com/sNpx6zL4

Comment: You seem to be getting nulls from row 83 onwards is this what you see?